# How to use mgconsole non-interactive mode to run queries?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is it possible to run queries in `mgconsole` non-interactively? I know that I can use a file that has query in it and redirect it, `mgconsole < test.txt`. I would like to avoid creating a file on a filesystem.

How can I pass Cypher query to `mgconsole`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use file for input you can use `echo` in combination with pipe, e.g.

```
echo "MATCH (n) RETURN n;" | mgconsole
```